# How to add child where parent element's attribute = x

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have an XML document with the following structure:

```
<position index="x">
     <character>y</character>
</position>
```

I need to be able to add a new character to a position based on its index. For example, where index = "3", add the character "g".

I know I can *find* an element with the following:

```
var query = from positions in myDoc.Descendants("position")
     where (string)positions.Attribute("index").Value == n
     select positions;
```

But I'm having trouble figuring out if I need a similar kind of query or construction to identify an element with attribute value x, then add child nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query already returns elements you want to add to, so it boils down to:

```
var query = from positions in myDoc.Descendants("position")
            where (string)positions.Attribute("index").Value == n
            select positions;
foreach (var position in query)
{
    position.Add(new XElement("character", "g"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @jimmy_keen. I'm getting the following error: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @tmoore82: are your adding in `foreach`? I've edited my answer, your code should look like this in order for it to work.

Comment: Nevermind. Knowing that the query only returned one value, I was trying to do it without the `foreach`. That was the source of the error.

Comment: Good call! Didn't see that comment until I posted my response. :)